# How to verify if the phone is docked?

Tags: android, dock, receiver

I'm looking for a way to verify if the phone is docked (car dock, desk dock) on Android 1.6 (API 4).
I know that there is a broadcast receiver android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT, but only for API 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no concept of a dock in API level 4. Hence, there is no way to determine if a device is docked in API level 4.

Comment: Ok, but the android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED is sent when the phone is put in the dock ? The user says that the dock is also charging his phone but the option "Always stay on while power is connected" of the display is not working when it is docked, so this make me think that it is possible that android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED to not be sent when docked...

Comment: @Alex: "Ok, but the android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED is sent when the phone is put in the dock ?" -- that would depend on the dock and whether it has a power connector, I imagine. "so this make me think that it is possible that android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED to not be sent when docked" -- I suppose it is possible, but I have no idea.